# How to preserve scroll position of a RecyclerView after a configuration change when using MVVM viewmodel and livedata?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

**READ FIRST:
Apologies, it seems I have played myself. I was using RecyclerView in my xml earlier, but switched it over for [CardStackView](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView) (it still uses the exact same RecyclerView adapter). If I switch back to RecyclerView, the original code  below works - the scroll position is saved and restored automatically on configuration change.**

I'm using a MVVM viewmodel class which successfully retains list data for a RecyclerView after a configuration change. However, the previous RecyclerView position is not restored. Is this expected behaviour? What would be a good way to solve this?

I saw a [blog post on medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334) briefly mentioning you can preserve scroll position by setting the adapter data before setting said adapter on the RecyclerView.
From what I understand, after a configuration change the livedata that was being observed earlier gets a callback. That callback is where I set my adapter data. But it seems this callback happens after the onCreate() function finishes by which point my RecyclerView adapter is already set.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val adapter = MovieAdapter()
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Create or retrieve viewmodel and observe data needed for recyclerview
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.movies.observe(this, {
            adapter.items = it
        })

        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        // If viewmodel has no data for recyclerview, retrieve it
        if (viewModel.movies.value == null) viewModel.retrieveMovies()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MovieAdapter :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {

    var items: List<Movie> by Delegates.observable(emptyList()) { _, _, _ ->
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val binding = ItemMovieCardBinding.bind(itemView)

        fun bind(item: Movie) {
            with(binding) {
                imagePoster.load(item.posterUrl)
                textRating.text = item.rating.toString()
                textDate.text = item.date
                textOverview.text = item.overview
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_movie_card, parent, false)

        return MovieViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size
}
```

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _movies = MutableLiveData<List<Movie>>()
    val movies: LiveData<List<Movie>> get() = _movies

    fun retrieveMovies() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val client = ApiClient.create()
            val result: Movies = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { client.getPopularMovies() }

            _movies.value = result.movies
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `is this expected behaviour?` a configuration change recreates the entire activity, it will go through onDestroy followed by onCreate, [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes), meaning it's a new activity you have, so yes, it's expected or normal. is this something which you really have to "fix", that depends on you. How you'd fix it ? i'm not sure :) If you find a reliable way of keeping the last visible item, you could probably use smoothScrollToPosition, or something similar

Comment: In your `observe()` lambda, there is `adapter.items = it`. What does `MovieAdapter` do when you set `items`? Does it call `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Can you update the question with the relevant code from the adapter?

Comment: @a_local_nobody According to the aforementioned blog: "_There are several ways to ensure a correct scroll position... The best one is making sure that you always set the data on the Adapter before the first layout pass by caching the data you want to display in memory, in a ViewModel_" . This led me to believe there is a special way to do this when it comes to ViewModel. I could, of course, create another variable inside the ViewModel class and save the scroll position ( `getBindingAdapterPosition()`) there before the Activity is destroyed, but is that really the best way is what I'm asking.

Comment: @BenP. It does call `notifyDataSetChanged()` as soon as it detects fresh data. I've updated the question with the adapter and viewmodel classes.

Answer (score 1):

Set adapter only after its items are available.

```
    viewModel.movies.observe(this, {
        adapter.items = it
        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter
    })
```